# Mimic a LinkedList with a simple float[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, linked-list

I have to draw on a SurfaceView the trails of some object moving around. The trail of an object is implemented as a LinkedList of points (a point is a pair of float coordinates on the SurfaceView). The LinkedList is motivated by a behaviour like that

```
    public class Trail extends LinkedList<Points> {

        private static int numbOfPoints;

        @Override
        public boolean add(Point point) {
            super.add(point);
            while( this.size() > Trail.numbOfPoints ) {
                super.remove();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

where numbOfPoints is the maximum number of trail points. If a new point is added then the oldest is removed from the trail to maintain fixed the trail size. But when I draw the points I would have a float[] rather than a LinkedList of Points in order to use canvas.drawPoints(float[]). So I came up with a manual conversion from LinkedList to float[] that is inefficient and causes some trouble...

So, there is a way to avoid the use of a LinkedList and store directly the coordinates into a float[] with the behaviour described above?

Comment: Are you aware of this data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer?

Comment: @user3707125 Thanks very interesting, but the problem is again the conversion into a plain array of floats... My question was: there is a way to get the desired behaviour using only arrays of floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to implement this is through a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). I don't really understand how you are drawing something on canvas using `float[]` instead of `float[][]`, but you should be able to make this solution use any type you like:

```
class Trail {
    private final int maxLength;

    private float[] points;
    private int start = 0;
    private int length = 0;

    private float[] buffer;

    public Trail(int maxLength) {
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        this.points = new float[maxLength];
        this.buffer = new float[0];
    }

    public void add(float point) {
        points[(start + length) % points.length] = point;
        if (length < maxLength) {
            length++;
        } else {
            start = (start + 1) % points.length;
        }
    }

    public float[] getTail() {
        if (buffer.length != length) { // Reusing the array if possible.
            buffer = new float[length];
        }
        int itemsFromStartToArrayEnd = Math.min(length, points.length - start);
        System.arraycopy(points, start, buffer, 0, itemsFromStartToArrayEnd);
        if (start + length > maxLength) {
            System.arraycopy(points, 0, buffer, itemsFromStartToArrayEnd, length - itemsFromStartToArrayEnd);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```